# Does Outlook.com support EWS?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook.com

Does Outlook.com support EWS? If no, what are the different ways to access a users tasks and calendar using python?

So far I have done the following:

Used [EWSWrapper](https://github.com/maiiku/EWSWrapper_py) and tried out using [suds-ews with python](http://blogs.it.ox.ac.uk/inapickle/2011/05/14/exchange-web-services-suds-and-python/). All these implementation fail when i try with an outlook.com account.

So here is what I want to know:

- If EWS is not available , what other ways can I do to retrieve task and calendar list .
- Is there a library in python that I can use which considers, earlier 2007 exchange servers, the newer once from 2010 to 2013 and does basic error handling.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Yes it supports now](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-provides-update-migration-new-outlook-com/)

> Microsoft migrated from the legacy infrastructure to latest Office 365 based infrastructure

Following code snippet in c# will send HelloWorld message via EWS from outlook.com

```
var service = new ExchangeService
{
    TraceEnabled = true,
    TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All,
    Credentials = new WebCredentials("user@outlook.com", "p@ssw0rd"),
    Url = new Uri("https://outlook.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
};

var email = new EmailMessage(service);

email.ToRecipients.Add("recipient@outlook.com");
email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API.");
email.Send();
```

For more code samples visit [EWS Managed API docs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api)

Comment: and if you wanted to do it with => new OAuthCredentials(accessToken) will it work?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the consumer facing Outlook.com (this is the Hotmail replacement, not to be confused with the Office 365 offering which uses the same root domain name) **does NOT support EWS**.  It only supports EAS.

See this thread:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-profile/i-want-to-access-outlookcom-account-over-exchange/83971a95-7fb3-483a-96fc-ac7e0299345b?msgId=71d12357-f735-4958-baef-39997b5802c8

Answer (score 0):

I'm a C#-Developer so I don't know how it works in Python, but EWS Managed API works with ExchangeOnline. I'm already using it.
Maybe you have to enable redicreting in the autodiscover. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365trainingcourse_10l_1_topic2

I tried to connect to Outlook.com with ServerVersion 2010 and 2013-Setting and both work fine.

Comment: Exchange Online (Office 365) is separate service from Outlook.com that runs on different software stack. Historically some Office 365 endpoints were accessible on the outlook.com domain, but that is no longer the case.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.com accounts do not support the EWS exchange service API especially when trying to use the oAuth2 token obtain from live.com.

It is recommended to try and use the REST API. The REST API is currently enabled on all Office 365 accounts that have Exchange Online and some Outlook.com accounts.

You can find more detailed information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224954/connecting-with-ews-api-service-to-outlook-com-account-with-oauth2-token) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started)