# Connecting with EWS API service to outlook.com account with oAuth2 token

Tags: outlook, openid, exchangewebservices

I'm able to authenticate with live.com with my account on outlook.com at url

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0
```

I receive an accessToken and id token.

My question is whether I can use **this accessToken** to retrieve exchange data about my emails through EWS API service using this token? ExchangeService.

```
   _exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1) { ConnectionGroupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
                    _exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "outlook.com");
                 //  _credentials = new OAuthCredentials(user.PasswordToken);
                    // Set the URL.
                    _exchangeService.TraceEnabled = true;
                    _exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl("xxxxx")
```

Authenticate to Outlook 365 through the ExchangeService.asmx in the following URL for exchange service as done in the following [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect).

```
> https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

My question is whether I can retrieve email data from exchange service ASMX with the idToken/accessToken supplied from live.com for outlook.com accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the retrieving of data with EWS Managed API **is not supported** with outlook.com accounts.

you can read (in the yellow section) about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started) and also [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api).

Basically, there are 2 portals today that apps can be created with:

1. [Application Registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)
2. [Azure management portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/)

It states that for these reasons outlook.com accounts are not supported:

1. New app registrations should be created and managed in the **new Application Registration Portal** to be compatible with Outlook.com. This means that if you have an app that was created thru Azure Management Portal it will not be supported with outlook.com and the token will not work with outlook.com accounts.
2. Existing app registrations that were created in the the Azure Management Portal will continue to work **for Office 365 only**
3. Also if you created your app with Application Registration Portal The REST API is currently enabled on all Office 365 accounts that have Exchange Online and **only some** Outlook.com accounts. this means it is not guaranteed to all outlook.com accounts because they haven't migrated all of them (yet).
4. Microsoft accounts with Outlook.com mailboxes (including Outlook.com, Hotmail.com, Live.com, MSN.com, and Passport.com) are in the process of being upgraded to enable the REST APIs. During this process, making API calls to mailboxes that are not yet upgraded will return a MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI or MailboxNotSupportedForRESTAPI error code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe EWS still works for Outlook.com accounts with BASIC(username,password) auth. We used to use it before migrating to Graph API. You'd need to ask your Outlook users to generate a special [App Password](https://www.getsetsolution.com/how-to-create-app-passwords-for-outlook) though.

To simplify your Exchange/Outlook integrations check out [Aurinko API](https://docs.aurinko.io/article/8-what-is-aurinko)